# JasperReports Server / iReport query not showing correct data

Tags: sql, jasper-reports, ireport, jasperserver

So here is a example of the exact query I want that displays the correct data.

```sql
select *
from `aaaa`
inner join `bbbb` on (`bbbb`.`bleble` = `aaaa`.`bleble`)
inner join `cccc` on (`cccc`.`bleble` = `bbbb`.`bleble`)
where `aaaa`.`ID` = 7294 
and `bbbb`.`langauge_id` = 3 
and `cccc`.`startdate` <= '2013-12-05' 
group by aaaa.ID
order by aaaa.ID
```

I've setup *iReport 5.0.0* to give me exactly that

When I run the report exactly the above query gets printed to the jasperserver logs (except for the Group by and Order by lines)

In *iReport* I added a Report group **aaaa.ID** and the report is ordered by **aaaa.ID**

But the only about a 1/8th of the data that should show is showing in *JasperReports Server*.

I'm assuming the issue is with the group by because the query in the logs is identical to the one i need except for that group by (which I added in *iReport*)

Why is the data in *JR Server* not showing correctly?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is too localized

Comment: Are you using the same connection in iReport and on JR Server? Maybe production/development DB mix up...

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Missing data (JasperReports Server reports)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19859743/876298)

Comment: If you mean that you added a Report Group in iReport, that's not the same as a GROUP BY in a query. Add the group by to your query. Can you show us what you have, and what you expect to get? Getting less data than you expect could be a result of (the proper functioning of) a query group by or a report group in iReport.

Comment: Realised it is a duplicate of : Missing data (JasperReports Server reports)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was jasperserver had a default row limit set of 2,000,000

I raised that limmit to 6,000,000 and BOOOM !!! it works now :)